# Topographic Correction Method for a Single Image SCS+C

Tags: google-earth-engine, topography

I am trying to code the SCS+C topographic correction method for a single image and a I get this error: "Image (Error) Image.constant: Parameter 'value' is required."
I have seen a similar script for an entire collection, but I only need for some specific images.

Here is the code that I have written:

```
/* *********************
               SCS+C Method for a Single Image 
                                  ********************* */


var demClip = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-97.83, 16.28, -95.05, 18.39)

// Definition of Landsat 5/7/8 bands and default band names
var oliBands = ['B2',   'B3',    'B4',  'B5',  'B6',    'B7'];
var tmEtmBands = ['B1',   'B2',    'B3',  'B4',  'B5',    'B7'];
var defBands = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2'];



//CONVERT TO RADIANS
function radians(img) {
  return img.toFloat().multiply(Math.PI).divide(180);}

//DEM, SLOPE, ASPECT
var DEM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003").clip(demClip);
var SLP = radians(ee.Terrain.slope(DEM));
var ASP = radians(ee.Terrain.aspect(DEM));

var scscTC = function(img) {
  var outImage = img.select([]);
  
  //Get the footprint image of the study area
  var footprint = ee.Geometry.Polygon(ee.Number(ee.List(img.get('system:footprint'))));

  //VARIABLES FROM METADATA
  var AZ = ee.Number(img.get('solar_azimuth_angle'));
  var ZE = ee.Number(img.get('solar_zenith_angle'));
  var AZ_R = radians(ee.Image(AZ));
  var ZE_R = radians(ee.Image(ZE));
  
  //CALCULATE LOCAL ILLUMINATION, COS OF THE SLOPE, AND COS OF THE ZENITH ANGLE
  var IL = AZ_R.subtract(ASP).cos().multiply(SLP.sin()).multiply(ZE_R.sin())
  .add(ZE_R.cos().multiply(SLP.cos()));
  var cos_ZE = ZE_R.cos();
  var cos_SLP = SLP.cos();
  

  //C for the blue band
  var clippedImg = img.addBands(1).addBands(IL);
  var resultBlue = clippedImg.select('constant', 'constant_1', 'blue')
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.linearRegression(2,1),
      geometry: footprint,
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 2e9
      });
  var blueC = (ee.Array(resultBlue.get('coefficients')).get([0,0]))
  .divide(ee.Array(resultBlue.get('coefficients')).get([1,0]));
  var blueCorr = ((cos_ZE.multiply(cos_SLP)).add(blueC)).divide(IL.add(blueC));

  
  //C for the green band
  var clippedImg = img.addBands(1).addBands(IL);
  var resultGreen = clippedImg.select('constant', 'constant_1', 'green')
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.linearRegression(2,1),
      geometry: footprint,
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 2e9
      });
  var greenC = (ee.Array(resultGreen.get('coefficients')).get([0,0]))
  .divide(ee.Array(resultGreen.get('coefficients')).get([1,0]));
  var greenCorr = ((cos_ZE.multiply(cos_SLP)).add(greenC)).divide(IL.add(greenC));
  
  //C for the red band
  var clippedImg = img.addBands(1).addBands(IL);
  var resultRed = clippedImg.select('constant', 'constant_1', 'red')
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.linearRegression(2,1),
      geometry: footprint,
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 2e9
      });
  var redC = (ee.Array(resultRed.get('coefficients')).get([0,0]))
  .divide(ee.Array(resultRed.get('coefficients')).get([1,0]));
  var redCorr = ((cos_ZE.multiply(cos_SLP)).add(redC)).divide(IL.add(redC));
  
  //C for the nir band
  var clippedImg = img.addBands(1).addBands(IL);
  var resultNir = clippedImg.select('constant', 'constant_1', 'nir')
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.linearRegression(2,1),
      geometry: footprint,
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 2e9
      });
  var nirC = (ee.Array(resultNir.get('coefficients')).get([0,0]))
  .divide(ee.Array(resultNir.get('coefficients')).get([1,0]));
  var nirCorr = ((cos_ZE.multiply(cos_SLP)).add(nirC)).divide(IL.add(nirC));
  
  //C for the swir1 band
  var clippedImg = img.addBands(1).addBands(IL);
  var resultSwir1 = clippedImg.select('constant', 'constant_1', 'swir1')
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.linearRegression(2,1),
      geometry: footprint,
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 2e9
      });
  var swir1C = (ee.Array(resultSwir1.get('coefficients')).get([0,0]))
  .divide(ee.Array(resultSwir1.get('coefficients')).get([1,0]));
  var swir1Corr = ((cos_ZE.multiply(cos_SLP)).add(swir1C)).divide(IL.add(swir1C));
  
  //C for the swir2 band
  var clippedImg = img.addBands(1).addBands(IL);
  var resultSwir2 = clippedImg.select('constant', 'constant_1', 'swir2')
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.linearRegression(2,1),
      geometry: footprint,
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 2e9
      });
  var swir2C = (ee.Array(resultSwir2.get('coefficients')).get([0,0]))
  .divide(ee.Array(resultSwir2.get('coefficients')).get([1,0]));
  var swir2Corr = ((cos_ZE.multiply(cos_SLP)).add(swir2C)).divide(IL.add(swir2C));
  
  //IMAGE CORRECTION
  var InImg2 = img.multiply(0.0001);
  
  var blueBand = InImg2.select('blue').multiply(blueCorr);
  //Map.addLayer(blueBand);
  var greenBand = InImg2.select('green').multiply(greenCorr);
  var redBand = InImg2.select('red').multiply(redCorr);
  var nirBand = InImg2.select('nir').multiply(redCorr);
  var swir1Band = InImg2.select('swir1').multiply(swir1Corr);
  var swir2Band = InImg2.select('swir2').multiply(swir2Corr);
  
  var img_TC = img.select().addBands([blueBand, greenBand, redBand, nirBand, swir1Band, swir2Band]);
  //print('img_TC', img_TC)
  
  //ADJUST VALUE RANGE (REFLECTANCE BETWEEN 0 AND 1)
  var img_TC1 = ((img_TC.multiply(10000)).int16())//.multiply(0.0001);
    
  outImage = outImage.addBands(img_TC1
  .select([0,1,2,3,4,5],['blue_TC', 'green_TC', 'red_TC', 'nir_TC', 'swir1_TC', 'swir2_TC']));
  return outImage
}



//////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Apply the SCS+C function to the image of interest
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
var inputImage = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_024048_20140322')
                    .select(oliBands, defBands);
print ("Original Image:", inputImage)
//------------------------------
var correctedImage = scscTC(inputImage);
print("Corrected Image: ", correctedImage)

Map.centerObject(inputImage, 9)
Map.addLayer(inputImage, {
  bands: ['swir2', 'nir', 'red'],
  min: 0,
  max: 10000,
  gamma:1.7
},
  "Original Image")
```

GEE LINK: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3087e98b22f9152a603837adedc9f301

Comment: " I have seen a similar script for an entire collection, but I only need for some specific images." Do you have the similar script link for an entire collection?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript distinguishs the lower case and the upper case. So, `'solar_azimuth_angle'` should be `'SOLAR_AZIMUTH_ANGLE'`, and `'solar_zenith_angle'` should be `'SOLAR_ZENITH_ANGLE'`.